# Oracle11g ORA-01403 No data found using Select Into

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, ora-06512, ora-01403

I am quite new to Oracle and I have an issue I have been struggelig With for some hours.

sample:

```
 Create Table Accounts (Id number(10),Balance number(16,3), Status Varchar2(50),Owner_Id number(10));
 Create Table Transactions (Id number(10),Amount number(16,3), Trxn_date date, Account_Id number(10));
 Create Table Owner (Id number(10), Firstname varchar2(50),Lastname varchar2(50));

 Insert Into Accounts(Id,Balance,Status,Owner_Id) Values (1,1000,'OPEN',10);
 Insert Into Accounts(Id,Balance,Status,Owner_Id) Values (2,5000,'CLOSED',11);
 Insert Into Accounts(Id,Balance,Status,Owner_Id) Values (3,1000,'OPEN',12);
 Insert Into Accounts(Id,Balance,Status,Owner_Id) Values (4,5000,'CLOSED',13);
 Insert Into Accounts(Id,Balance,Status,Owner_Id) Values (5,1000,'OPEN',14);
 Insert Into Accounts(Id,Balance,Status,Owner_Id) Values (6,5000,'CLOSED',15);
 Insert Into Accounts(Id,Balance,Status,Owner_Id) Values (7,1000,'OPEN',16);
 Insert Into Accounts(Id,Balance,Status,Owner_Id) Values (8,5000,'CLOSED',17);
 Insert Into Accounts(Id,Balance,Status,Owner_Id) Values (9,1000,'OPEN',18);
 Insert Into Accounts(Id,Balance,Status,Owner_Id) Values (10,5000,'CLOSED',19);
 Insert Into Accounts(Id,Balance,Status,Owner_Id) Values (11,1000,'OPEN',20);
 Insert Into Accounts(Id,Balance,Status,Owner_Id) Values (12,5000,'CLOSED',21);

 Insert Into Owner(Id,Firstname,Lastname) Values (10,'John','TEST1');
 Insert Into Owner(Id,Firstname,Lastname) Values (11,'John','TEST2');
 Insert Into Owner(Id,Firstname,Lastname) Values (10,'John','TEST3');
 Insert Into Owner(Id,Firstname,Lastname) Values (11,'John','TEST4');
 Insert Into Owner(Id,Firstname,Lastname) Values (10,'John','TEST5');
 Insert Into Owner(Id,Firstname,Lastname) Values (11,'John','TEST6');
 Insert Into Owner(Id,Firstname,Lastname) Values (10,'John','TEST7');
 Insert Into Owner(Id,Firstname,Lastname) Values (11,'John','TEST8');
 Insert Into Owner(Id,Firstname,Lastname) Values (10,'John','TEST9');
 Insert Into Owner(Id,Firstname,Lastname) Values (11,'John','TEST10');
 Insert Into Owner(Id,Firstname,Lastname) Values (10,'John','TEST11');
 Insert Into Owner(Id,Firstname,Lastname) Values (11,'John','TEST12');

 Insert Into Transactions(Id,Amount,Trxn_Date,Account_Id) Values (1,10,'02-FEB-2015',5);
 Insert Into Transactions(Id,Amount,Trxn_Date,Account_Id) Values (2,10,'02-APR-2015',5);
 Insert Into Transactions(Id,Amount,Trxn_Date,Account_Id) Values (3,10,'02-JUN-2015',5);
 Insert Into Transactions(Id,Amount,Trxn_Date,Account_Id) Values (4,10,'02-AUG-2015',5);
 Insert Into Transactions(Id,Amount,Trxn_Date,Account_Id) Values (5,10,'02-FEB-2015',2);
 Insert Into Transactions(Id,Amount,Trxn_Date,Account_Id) Values (6,10,'02-APR-2015',2);
 Insert Into Transactions(Id,Amount,Trxn_Date,Account_Id) Values (7,10,'02-JUN-2015',2);
 Insert Into Transactions(Id,Amount,Trxn_Date,Account_Id) Values (8,10,'02-AUG-2015',2);
```

Data Check:

```
   Select Unique(Account_Id) From Accounts A
 Inner Join Owner B on B.ID=A.OWNER_ID 
 Inner Join Transactions I on I.ACCOUNT_ID=A.Id
   Where I.Trxn_date Between '01-FEB-2015' and '01-JUL-2015' 
 And A.Status='CLOSED'
 and A.Balance=5000;/*1 Row Returned*/
```

The Loop must exit at first Id returned

```
   Declare
   l_NewDate date:='01-FEB-2015';
   l_OldDate date:='01-JUL-2015';
   l_pID number(10);

 Begin
   For I in (Select Account_Id From Transactions 
   Where Trxn_date Between l_NewDate and l_OldDate)

   Loop

   Select Id Into l_pID From 
   (Select B.Id From Accounts A 
   Inner Join Owner B on A.Owner_Id = B.Id
   Where A.Status = 'CLOSED' And A.Balance = 5000 And A.Id=I.Account_Id)
   Where rownum < 2;
   dbms_output.put_line(l_pID);
   Exit;

   End Loop;
   End;

 ORA-01403: No data found

 ORA-06512: at line 12
```

I fail to understand why no data is found when the data check above clearly states otherwise.

Regards
J. Olsen

Answer (score 1):

Like you say, your data check query:

```
Select Unique(Account_Id)
  From Accounts A
 Inner Join Owner B on B.ID=A.OWNER_ID 
 Inner Join Transactions I on I.ACCOUNT_ID=A.Id
 Where I.Trxn_date Between '01-FEB-2015' and '01-JUL-2015' 
   And A.Status='CLOSED'
   and A.Balance=5000;
```

... returns a single row with a single `Account_Id` value of `2`.

But then, your PL/SQL code basically splits the logic in 2 queries. The query you loop on is:

```
Select Account_Id
  From Transactions 
 Where Trxn_date Between '01-FEB-2015' and '01-JUL-2015'
```

And, when I run it, it returns:

```
5
5
5
2
2
2
```

Now the above's order is not guaranteed, as you don't have an `ORDER BY` clause. But if you get the results in the same order as me, then your first loop iteration will execute the next query using `5` as input:

```
Select *
  From Accounts A 
 Inner Join Owner B on A.Owner_Id = B.Id
 Where A.Status = 'CLOSED'
   And A.Balance = 5000
   And A.Id = 5
```

... which doesn't return any data, which is why you get your error.

If you would have been lucky enough to have started with the value of `2`:

```
Select *
  From Accounts A 
 Inner Join Owner B on A.Owner_Id = B.Id
 Where A.Status = 'CLOSED'
   And A.Balance = 5000
   And A.Id = 2
```

... it would have worked as expected.

I wish I could recommend a proper solution, but I just don't truly understand what you are trying to do.  But it certainly feels like you shouldn't need PL/SQL loops to do what you want.  A simple query should be sufficient.  Your data check query seems like a good start.

**EDIT**

For what it's worth, I think this is a more straight forward way of doing the exact same thing you are intending to do (no loops):

```
Declare
   l_NewDate date:='01-FEB-2015';
   l_OldDate date:='01-JUL-2015';
   l_pID number(10);
 Begin
   select o.id into l_pID
    from transactions t
    join accounts a
      on a.id = t.account_id
     and a.status = 'CLOSED'
     and a.balance = 5000
    join owner o
      on o.id = a.owner_id
   where t.trxn_date between l_NewDate and l_OldDate
     and rownum < 2;

  dbms_output.put_line(l_pID);
End;
```

Comment: Thank you for assisting me. What I am trying to achieve is to extract the first available account that pass my criteria and select the owner Id into variable l_pID. The tables I have created above is in reality a simplification of what my actual data looks like. In reality, the transaction table is a complex table with millions of rows. Same applies to owner and account table. The problem is two things:
1. Full table access of Transaction table is very slow.
2. Account does not necessary need to have transactions. I could use 
"left outer join" however, this is also very slow.

Comment: Slow way to resolve it.


    select Unique(O.Id) 
    from Accounts A
    Inner Join Owner O on O.Id=A.OWNER_ID
    Left outer join Transactions T on T.ACCOUNT_ID=A.Id
    Where A.Status = 'CLOSED'
    and A.Balance =5000
    And Trxn_date Between '01-FEB-2015' and '01-JUL-2015'
    And rownum < 2;